# github actionsでwebhookurlを用いてslack通知しようとすると403エラーが出る

Tags: github, slack, github-actions

github actionsでwebhookurlを用いてslack通知しようとすると発生する403エラーを解決したい。

もともとpushやmergeをトリガーにgit errorを検知することでslack通知を送るプログラムを考えていたため以下のようなコードの構成にしました。

```
name: Slack Notification

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  slack_notification:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Detect Merge Conflict
        id: conflict_check
        run: |
          git fetch origin develop
          git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD origin/develop
          CONFLICT=$?
          echo "::set-output name=conflict::$CONFLICT"

      - name: Send Slack notification
        uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2.0.0
        env:
          SLACK_CHANNEL: "test"
          SLACK_MESSAGE: "Pushed to branch by ${{ github.actor }}. Merge conflict: ${{ steps.conflict_check.outputs.conflict }}"
          SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ var.WEBHOOKURL }}
```

発生したエラーは以下のようになります。

１．merge conflictを意図的に発生させたもの(本当はここでエラー検知した時もslack通知したい)

```
Run # Fetch the current develop branch
  # Fetch the current develop branch
  git fetch origin develop
  # Check if the current commit is ancestor of the master branch
  git merge-base --is-ancestor HEAD origin/develop
  CONFLICT=$?
  # Save the exit code (merge conflict information) to the output of this step
  echo "::set-output name=conflict::$CONFLICT"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
From https://github.com/Spacee-Inc/deploy
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

２．処理が正常終了してもslack通知がいかなくて非推奨警告が来る。

```
slack_notification
The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
```

Comment: "非推奨警告が来る" で表示された URL に対応方法が記載されていますが、そちらは読まれましたか？

Comment: 質問文に書かれているログには 403 エラーとは書かれていませんが、どこから 403 だと判断なされましたか？

Answer (score 1):

SLACK_WEBHOOK に正しい値を設定できていないです。`var.WEBHOOKURL` を参照していますが、存在していなくて空文字になっていそうです。

- 秘匿値を利用したいのであれば `secrets.WEBHOOKURL`
- 構成変数を利用したいのであれば `vars.WEBHOOKURL`（var ではなくて var**s**）
- 環境変数を利用したいのであれば `env.WEBHOOKURL`

です。いずれの場合も値の設定も忘れず行うようにしてください。詳しくはドキュメントを参照してください：

- https://docs.github.com/ja/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets
- https://docs.github.com/ja/actions/learn-github-actions/variables

`::set-output` の deprecation warning は warning なだけでこのメッセージが出ているならまだ動くので、Slack 通知が来ないこととは関係ないはずです。それはそれとして対応した方が良いのですが。

また SLACK_MESSAGE についても https://github.com/rtCamp/action-slack-notify#environment-variables によると "It is advised not to override this." とのことです。